# Plot graph of zeta(s) for s between -10 and 0

Tags: tikz-pgf

Please can someone help me?
I want to plot this in Latex?
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=zeta%28s%29%2C+s+from+-15+to+0
Thank you

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic for this site because it is of the do-this-one-off-job-for-me variety that is unlikely to be of interest to others. The fact that the posting shows no research effort is also discouraging.

Comment: If you use sagetex through Sagemath Cloud then it's trivial:\sageplot[width=4cm]{plot(zeta(x), (x, -10, 0),ymin=-.2, ymax=.07)}.

Comment: @Mico While I agree that the question could definitely use a lot of improvement, I've voted to leave the question open. TeX.SX is littered with such questions, and the usual policy seems to be that they don't get closed.

Comment: @AdamLiter - It would definitely be welcome if the OP edited the query to show some research effort, right?

Comment: @Mico Agreed, but I think we should let the OP have the chance to do that before the question gets closed.